# Displaying certain sections of a form with accordion UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel-4

I have a rather long form where a user has to fill in some sections and leave others blank depending on their circumstances and then I will save the sections to a database. To help visitors stay organized I have utilized jQuery UI's Accordion to divide the form into sections.

Now that the form is built I'm trying to find a way to display just the sections they filled in so they can print them off. If I simply bring up the form and they try to print it, it will print the accordion sections.

Right now I'm thinking of getting all the div's that have inputs filled in, combining them, and then sending them off to the DB to be saved so I can call them up later. This seems a little sloppy to me and I would prefer something tidier and that would be considered "best practices." If anyone has a better, neater, more efficient way of doing this I would appreciate your input! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made something similar for my work. I gathered the fields that were actually filled in and created an overview on the same page using jQuery. Rendering this info on the client and on the same page saves you from a server/database call.

We used jQuery serialize() for fetching the filled in input fields and labels and created a JavaScript object with the values so we could render these in an overview. This overview would render in the page when clicking a `check form` button, then if the user is not satisfied they can go back to the form by cancel or proceed.

You might want to split it up into tasks:

- Store relevant form HTML in a variable
- Filter out the fields that are empty
- If necessary reorder the HTML
- Render the HTML for viewing and printing